# For loop that iterates through files and iteratively appends lists storing values from the read file

Tags: python, performance

How can I fasten this code, that reads a text file sequentially and appends a list? fp and fp_2 reads two different files from the same sub-sirectory here

```
import os
import glob
from IPython import embed
import numpy as np


dirs = os.listdir("/home/Set/")

poseList = [] #Store poses for all files
featuresList = [] # Store features

def data():
    for dir_name in dirs: 
        fp = '/home/Set/left'
        fp_2 =  '/home/Set/fc/fc2_0.npy'
        if os.path.exists(fp) and os.path.exists(fp_2):
            files = glob.glob(fp+"/*.txt")
            curr_pose = []  #Store curr pose
            for f in files:
                with open(f) as pose:
                    pl = pose.readlines()
                    pl = [p.strip() for p in pl] 
                    pl = map(float, pl)  # str ->float
                    curr_pose.append((pl))
            poseList.append(curr_pose)   #append to main list 
            featuresList.append(np.load(fp_2))
        print "Not available", dir_name

data()    
embed()
```

Comment: Also what is this meant to do, is it meant to repeatedly open `fp` and `fp_2`? Why not just read the files once?

Comment: @Peilonrayz fp and fp2 read two different files under the same sub-folder

Comment: Why are they wrapped in `for dir_name in dirs:` if they never change?

Comment: @Peilonrayz My bad, `dir_name` is the folder name. `fp` and `fp_2` read files in different sub-folders under the same folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Variable naming

Your variable's names do not convey their purpose and are even misleading.
E.g. `fp` and `fp_2` suggest file pointers, but are actually strings.
Notwithstanding, for a better reference, I will use your variable names below.

You should also implement PEP8 (`poseList` vs. `pose_list` etc.).

## Recurring declaration

You keep redefining the same constants `fp` and `fp_2` in a loop:

```
for dir_name in dirs: 
    fp = '/home/Set/left'
    fp_2 =  '/home/Set/fc/fc2_0.npy'
```

Better declare them beforehand:

```
fp = '/home/Set/left'
fp_2 =  '/home/Set/fc/fc2_0.npy'

for dir_name in dirs:
```

## Avoiding race conditions

By checking for existing files and folders using

```
if os.path.exists(fp) and os.path.exists(fp_2):
```

you've created yourself a race condition.
It is better to just try to open the file and handle the respective exception raised if something goes wrong.

## Joining paths

Your path concatenation

```
fp+"/*.txt"
```

might work for you.
But there is `os.path.join` to do this safely and get a sanitized path:

```
os.path.join(fp, "*.txt")  # Leading "/" removed!
```

Just for the record: In Python 3 (which you are not using assuming from your print statement) you can use `pathlib.Path` to handle your paths:

```
fp = Path('/home/Set/left')
…
str(fp.joinpath('*.txt'))
```

## Reading lines

Files are *iterable*, so you can get a file's lines more easily:

```
for f in files:
    with open(f) as pose:
        pl = [line.strip() for line in pose] 
        …
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Neumann's  answer, you can save your processor from executing several repeated instructions by checking first the existence of the `fp` and `fp_2` files once for all, and then loop as much as there are entries within `dirs`.

In plain code, this is what I mean:

```
# ...
# ...
FP = '/home/Set/left' # You should pick better names and capitalize your constants' names
fp_2 =  '/home/Set/fc/fc2_0.npy'

def data():
    if os.path.exists(FP) and os.path.exists(fp_2): # Switch this line
        for dir_name in dirs: # With this line             
            files = glob.glob(FP+"/*.txt")
            curr_pose = []  
            # ....
            # the rest of your code ...
```